# What's the relation between the serial connector RS232-DB9 and 10 pin cable?

Tags: cables, pins

I bought one refurbished TP-LINK switch model TL-SL3452:

[image]

and I needed to restore it to factory settings. To do that I tried to connect the serial cable but I accidentally broke one of the pins on the connector RS232-DB9:

[image]

so I thought that I could replaced it, to do that I opened the switch to see how things was connected and I saw that the RS232-DB9 connector that connected to the motherboard via a 10-pin cable.

[image]

so I removed the cable from the switch to see if was possible to change the RS232-DB9 connector:

[image]

and I discovered that the head of the  RS232-DB9 connector is removable (yay) so I removed it and released all the pins connected (stupid):

[image]

and with a new  RS232-DB9 connector:

[image]

I tried do solder the new connector in the wires as was before. But I think I got this wrong because the serial communication is not working.

so, what's the relation between the serial connector RS232-DB9 and 10 pin cable?

General image of the cable:

[image]

Image of the pin relation in the 10 pin cable tested with multimeter (red is 1):
[image]

Comment: 9 pin connector!  Now this is a great question for the Google.  In Google, we trust!

Comment: As that is not a simple linear mapping of one connector type to the other with a pin left unused, you're going to have to figure out which pin the wire was supposed to go on by looking for the one with leftover solder, or looking up the pinout of the board, or watching it run with a scope and trying things...

Comment: Where exactly did this cable come from? was it part of the switch or part of your PC? the manual for the TL-SL3452 doesn't seem to mention any 9 pin D connectors.

Comment: Most motherboards (but not all) use the same pinout. Use Google to look up the pin identification for the 10 pin header. Specifically, how to identify pin 1 and where the remainder of the pins are. It is a very simple pinout. Now just wire the same pin numbers together. That is: pin 1 to pin 1, etc. The 10th pin is a no-connect.

Comment: If nothing else works, get another of those switches (broken parts unit is fine) and examine how it is wired.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I tried to update the question with more information.

Comment: @DwayneReid I tried this with no success: https://www.crystalfontz.com/products/document/1895/xWR232Y13_mech_mm.png.pagespeed.ic.WVuJjBYc35.png

Comment: Unused would be pin 10.  And that has to be the worst soldering job I have ever seen.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat...  ViníciusLara, you need to get a better soldering tool, and maybe a better tool for stripping the wire. Without proper tools, even the person with the best soldering skills wouldn't be capable of doing a good job. Besides that, it seems that, beneath the parth of solder, you solved the problem of the broken pin. But, if you still can't do serial communication, I would ask you to which kind of equipment or adapter did you connect this DB9 port to. Are you aware that cannonical RS232 is not the same thing that TTL serial?

Comment: @mguima I really appreciate that, can you suggest some reading about soldering and soldering machines? Its the first time that I am doing this kinda of thing.

Comment: About soldering machines: the sky (or your money) is the limit. There are digitally controlled stations, but, for most uses, they're overkill. For hobby use, a simple analog solder station with temperature control seems good enough. This kind of equipment is heavy, so, I wouldn't recomend buying it from China - because of freight costs. Do a search in "MercadoLivre" for "Hikari estação 936". Hikari a Brazilian vendor that sells a Chinese-made device, and I'm very happy with mine. "936" design is a "standard", so, it's easy to find soldering tips and parts (the iron can be replaced, if needed).

Comment: @mguima Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the manual says not to use flow control all you likely really need is to find TX, RX, and ground and connect a terminal at 38400,N,8,1 and to disable flow control in your PC terminal program.

The additional pins should not need connection at all, provided that you disable flow control such that your PC is willing to transmit with them unconnected.

You appear to already have candidate connections for TX and RX and Ground on pins 2, 3, and 5.

**You may need to consider a cross-over between RX and TX depending on how they are defined.** (*Confirmed in comments - this was the issue*)

It's also entirely possible that your issue is not with the serial connection, but with the firmware of the device or the software you are using on your PC or anything like an outboard USB-RS232 adapter.

Do make sure you are using a USB-RS232 (eg which came with a 9 pin connector on it) and not a logic level USB-UART sold for Arduino projects...

Comment: Hey, I am using a fresh new USB TO RS232-DB9 cable, it says that is a USB 2.2 HI-SPEED CERTIFIED in the box.

Comment: Do a loopback test on the adapter cable: see that with pins 2-3 shorted if you type something you get *one more* copy of the character with the pins shorted than without, ie, you either get 2 with and 1 without or 1 with and none without.

Comment: @ViníciusLara Those vendors are so funny... USB 2.2 Hi speed... The maximum throughput of RS232 is 20 Kbps, which would perfectly fit in an USB 1.0 connection.

Comment: @mguima actually, no, it's not a perfect fit due to the issue of USB latency which in some situations can notoriously become a practical issue and make things which used to work well perform terribly when proxied over USB.   In theory with careful design at every stage, USB high speed could yield lower latency, but in practice, no, it's just marketing mumble and likely not even true.

Comment: I am also using PuTTY (Windows) connected to my COM5 (where the USB is) with 38400 of baud rate (speed), 8 data bits, 1 stop bits, no parity and no flow control. When I connect the adapter RX to RT using a jumper cable everything I type in the terminal I receive back once. If I type "h" I receive "h" not "hh". Is that okay?

Comment: @ViníciusLara yes, that's a good test and great news for the USB RS232 cable.  Try both RX vs TX possibilities vs the switch.  But realistically, this is a product usage question which is off topic for EESE.

Comment: Yep, connecting TX to pin 3, RX to pin 2 and Ground to pin 5 I was able to see the switch boot and interact with it. You have no idea how much I thank you. I spent several nights on it.

Comment: Do you have some recommendations in this kinda of topic to help me learn?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I sincerely want to thank you for all the friendship and kindness of all the detailed corrections you have made regarding the frequent mistakes I have made in EE.SE. I would in fact have already stopped accessing this site, if it weren't for the special incentive represented by your constant attention to all of my posts, and the always necessary corrections that you have always made to each every single minor error I've made. For example, like now, when you clarifyed that an USB 2.x adapter, of course, can be more efficient than USB 1.x for transfering a data stream from RS232.

Answer (score 1):

There are two "standards".

https://pinoutguide.com/Motherboard/rs232_header_pinout.shtml

A) carries pin numbering through (ribbon cable wire #2 goes to D-sub pin 2)

B) carries pin location through (ribbon cable wire #2 goes to D-sub pin 6)

B is more common (in my experience).  The B wiring is what you would get if the D-sub were an insulation-displacement connector like the header.

To determine which way your cable was wired, make a table of the wires you know are correct/unchanged, with one column for the wire number (start counting with the red wire as #1) and one column for the D-sub pin # (it is molded into the plastic body).  then see which standard it agrees with, and follow that for the pins you are concerned about.

Comment: The picture makes it obvious that neither of those exactly applies.  See the doubled up connection to pin 5?  It might be a variation of the pin number scheme, but one which forces certain signals...   The asker is going to have to do more research.

Comment: As I read it, the picture is of a connector that has been modified (incorrectly) by the TS.

Comment: I believe they were trying to replicate the original wiring but lost track part way through.  Anyway, it turns out that only 3 wires are needed.